# Windows 7 dual boot Ubuntu. Install. Reinstall.

Tags: re-installation

I have a dual boot Win 7 with Ubuntu.

Now, Win 7 got some problem. Not loading.

Ubuntu is working. But in system information it shows that it is Ubuntu 64 bit. But I don't have a 64 bit system. I have 32 bit. So, I want to uninstall it and reinstall 32 bit Ubuntu.

I have no idea how can i do that. Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Download a 32-bit ubuntu iso first, make a bootable thumb drive and install that in the partition that your current ubuntu has been installed.

Comment: If Ubuntu 64-bit is working you **do** have a 64-bit system. It would not even boot otherwise.

Comment: Yes, Takkat, Strange but it shows 32 bit in Win 7 and 64-bit in Ubuntu. Both worked well for more than 3 months.

Comment: So you have like most people running a 32-bit Windows on a 64-bit machine. Go ahead and use Ubuntu 64-bit!

Answer (score 0):

Simply pop in a Ubuntu live CD/USB and boot from it!

Firstly head over to the Ubuntu download page [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and download the 32bit .iso

Once you have done that open up "Start up disk creator" in Ubuntu and grab a blank CD/DVD/USB and choose that along with the .iso you have just downloaded. note: some computer's won't boot from USB if they are quite old so if you can use a CD/DVD.

Once the process has completed reboot your computer with the CD/DVD/USB in the computer and boot into it. This can be done my either pressing F12 on most computers or entering the bios to change the boot order, here put you CD/DVD drive at the top if you have burned to a CD/DVD or "removable storage" if you have burned to a USB.
Once booted you will get an option to "install Ubuntu", from here choose the configuration you want, e.g. Erase Windows and reinstall, Install alongside Windows etc.

Once this process has completed you will have a brand new working Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

If you need anymore help let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try and let you know.